# NHibernate - How to update sort order

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to update several records with a database through NHibernate.

The direct SQL query looks like:

update records set sortOrder = sortOrder +1 where sortOrder >= 3 and sortOrder <= 100

Is this possible in NHibernate?  I don't want to take the approach of pulling each record and updating them one at a time since this method can be used on databases with several thousand records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to send a command to the DB to do the update. If that's the case, you can use the CreateSQLQuery method on the session object to do so. [More info here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-nativesql).

If you are trying to persist multiple objects at once, you'll need to do a batch update. [More info on this from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780940/batch-update-in-nhibernate).

Comment: Is CreateSQLQuery platform independent?  I thought I read where Criteria > HQL > SQL in regards to platform independence, but I might be wrong.

Comment: CreateSQLQuery is not platform independent. You could make calls that in theory different DBs may not support.

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking for.  It worked perfectly for what I was needing to do.

Thanks a lot for your help.