# NHibernate update records via HQL

Tags: .net, nhibernate, hql

Does the last NHibernate version support record updates via HQL ?! 
 What about this statement?

```
 UPDATE Table_1 SET Value=Value+@Increment, @Result=1
        WHERE Id=@Id AND Value+@Increment<=@MaxLimit;SELECT @Result
```

Is it possible to execute above statement and get @Result via plane sql (CreateSqlQuery) at least ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do batch updates and deletes via HQL.

See @Mpritch's answer to the following question for an example: [Batch Update in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780940/batch-update-in-nhibernate)

And as you mentioned, you could always use sql or a stored proc to do the update.

I believe RowCount is what you are looking for in terms of @Result data