# nhibernate : executing updates in batches

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to do batch updates using NHibernate, but it is not doing batch updates, its doing individual writes for all the rows. I have to write around 10k rows to db.

```
        using (var session = GetSessionFactory().OpenStatelessSession())
        {
            session.SetBatchSize(100);
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                foreach (var pincode in list)
                {
                    session.Update(pincode);
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
```

I have tried setting batch size to 100 using `session.SetBatchSize(100);` but that does not help. Also tried setting batch size using `cfg.SetProperty("adonet.batch_size", "100");` but thats also not helping.

I am using GUID primary keys, hence I dont understand the reason for batch update failure. This is exactly the solution explained [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/desktopdev/mstech/nhibernate-making-updates-and-inserts-mu/). But its not working for me.

**NOTE** I have version field for optimistic concurrency mapped on all the entities. can that be the culprit for not having batch updates??

**EDIT**

i tried using  state-ful session but that also did not help

```
        //example 2
        using (var session = GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            session.SetBatchSize(100);
            session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
            foreach (var pincode in list)
            {
                session.Update(pincode);
            }
            session.Flush();
        }

       //example 3
        using (var session = GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            session.SetBatchSize(100);
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                foreach (var pincode in list)
                {
                    session.Update(pincode);
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
```

`example 2` for some reason is causing double round trips.

**EDIT**

after further research I found that, each session.Update is actually updating the db

```
        using (var session = SessionManager.GetStatelessSession())
        {
            session.SetBatchSize(100);
            foreach (var record in list)
            {
                session.Update(record);
            }
        }
```

how can I avoid that.

**EDIT**

tried with flush mode as well, but thats also not helping

```
        using (var session = SessionManager.GetNewSession())
        {
            session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never;
            session.SetBatchSize(100);
            session.BeginTransaction();
            foreach (var pincode in list)
            {
                session.SaveOrUpdate(pincode);
            }
            session.Flush();
            session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
```

**EDIT 4**

even below one is not working, given i am fetching all entities in same session and updating and saving them in that session only...

```
        using (var session = SessionManager.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            session.SetBatchSize(100);
            session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
            session.Transaction.Begin();
            var list = session.QueryOver<Pincode>().Take(1000).List();
            list.ForEach(x => x.Area = "Abcd" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssfff"));
            foreach (var pincode in list) session.SaveOrUpdate(pincode);
            session.Flush();
            session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
```

Comment: If your "pincode"'s are proxies, you should not need to call `session.Update(pincode);` If so, what happens if you change the entities and just call `session.Flush();`?

Comment: nopes these are not proxies, these object are fetch from db in another stateless session, some business logic applied and then batch saved...

Comment: In that case see Oskar's answer below.

Comment: but its the same even with state-ful sessions, see example 2, example 3 and recent edit... nothing is working to make updates in batches

Comment: As far as I know, if your entities are being fetched from a different session, you are still stateless. Try fetching, changing entities and committing using the same stateful session. See if that works.

Comment: checkout edit4, even fetch/update in same session is not doing bulk updates

Comment: How do you determine that it is "not doing batch updates"? What do you expect, what do you see?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger : i am using nh-prof, it is showing individual updates

Comment: There is no reason to call SaveOrUpdate() on an object that is already known to a stateful session. The session already tracks the object.

Comment: What SQL server is this?

Comment: @OskarBerggren : Sql Server 2008, you are right, even without SaveOrUpdate() the data is getting saved, but still one row at a time... i am using NHProf to check this.

Comment: RE: Edit4 does removing this line `foreach (var pincode in list) session.SaveOrUpdate(pincode);` still have the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, removing that line still has same behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nhibernate **does not batch versioned entities** that was the issue in my case.

There is no way you can batch version entities, the only to do this is to make the entity non versioned.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a stateless session. Since a stateless session has no state, it cannot remember anything to do later. Hence the update is executed immediately.

Comment: In my case, NHibernate stateless session was not flushing the update at all. The fix was to SetBatchSize(1).

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

- Batches are **not visible in Sql Server Profiler**. Do not depend on that.
- When **inserting** using **identity** (or native) id generators, NH turns off ado.net batch size.

Additional notes:

- make sure that you do not have a query for each changed entity, because it flushes before queries.
- You probably should not call session.Update. In the best case, it doesn't do anything. In worst case, it really does updating thus breaking batching.

When doing having many objects in the session, don't forget to care about flushes and flush time. Sometimes flushing is more time consuming than updating. NH flushes before commit, when you call flush and before queries, unless you turned it off or you use a stateless session. Make sure that you only flush once.

Comment: 1. I am using NHProf, 2. I have GUID primary keys. Also check the EDIT4, atleast that should work with session-flush

Comment: is there any other condition apart from these two which can break batching??

Comment: batching is implemented by ado.net, so the database must be accessed using ado.net.

Comment: the inserts are batched, so its not that batching is not working... its working for inserts but not for updates.

Comment: I have checked also the nhibernate logs, but there is nothing in logs which can tell, why its not using batching, every-time in abstract-batcher it processing single update.

Comment: You do not show working code in your question. There are no real updates made on the entities. Are you really calling Update for each entity? Are there also queries around?

Comment: i have purposefully kept the question with sample code which do represent the real problem domain. it boils down to, how to do bulk update for entities which are not attached to the session